# sonarQube VSCode Set up

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, visual-studio-code

i am trying to configure sonarQube in vscode for Javascript codes. 
i m trying to configure the source path as app/**/*.js
but it throws that execution failed. 
If i give a path of one particular file,  it works. 
Secondly,  i m not able to configure a sonarQube server with my credentials,  it ask for auth code.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In your case, SonarQube version, vscode version, screenshot, what did you try, etc..

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use wildcards in your source path. Simply configure it as *app*, and that directory will be searched recursively. All files with recognized file extensions will automatically be found and analyzed.